# Error code 8076 when creating tags

Tags: macos, finder, error, finder-tag

There is an extremely annoying bug that happens when I create a tag. I am tagging a bunch of .pdf files with author names. I enter the name in the tag box, press enter, then click on the next file that I want to tag. Then the error box appears telling me that the operation couldn't be done. But the weird thing is that the tag has been created when I go back to check. Furthermore, the error does not occur if I first click on the file again before clicking on the next file that I want to tag. I have the latest macOS.

Comment: Error code -8076 is a permission issue - so it's normal that the tag appeared when you checked again. Are the PDF located on your Mac or on an external storage ?

Comment: @tama no this is on the internal drive